# How do you manually dequeue a message using a Python Azure Functions QueueTrigger?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-queues

I'm using an Azure Functions Queue Trigger to read in a queue message and process work in Python. I have my `batchSize` parameter set to `1` to limit concurrency. In the Python code, I have an additional check to see if the work is ready to be processed as in:

```
if work is ready:
    do_work()
else:
    dequeue the message and try again
```

I want to dequeue the message if the work isn't ready to be processed and try again in one minute. I think I can achieve the retry by just setting `visibilityTimeout` to `00:01:00`. But what is the best way to dequeue the message? Would it just be:

```
if work is ready:
    do_work()
else:
    raise Exception("work is not ready, dequeue the message")
```

Would this allow the message to be dequeued and picked up for a retry in one minute? This use case is fairly rare and I'm wondering if there is a better way because I'm not sure if I want to see the Error in my logs for this case.

Edit: is it possible to use `initialVisibilityDelay` in my Python QueueTrigger? This would eliminate the need for me to throw an exception if I could delay the visibility of my messages by one minute.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to use initialVisibilityDelay in my Python
> QueueTrigger?

How are you putting your messages to the queue initially? If it's with the [Azure Queue storage output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=python), then I think you can't easily set the initial visibility delay.

You can however archieve what you want by using the queue's [put_message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/storage/azure-storage-queue/azure.storage.queue.queueservice.queueservice?view=storage-py-v2#put-message-queue-name--content--visibility-timeout-none--time-to-live-none--timeout-none-) function:

```
put_message(queue_name, content, visibility_timeout=None, time_to_live=None, timeout=None)
```

As you can see, it accepts the **visibility_timeout** parameter to make a message "active" after a specific delay, which is what you're after if I understood correctly.

Comment: I'm using an event grid subscription on Blob Created events. I'd prefer to use the event grid instead of creating a new Azure Function that uses `put_message()` because it would save resources